# Google chrome on ubuntu shows HUGE tabs

Tags: linux, google-chrome, ubuntu-14.04

I just booted up and it was like this, everything is zoomed in, but only in Chrome. Even the menu's in chrome are huge. Is this normal? How can I bring this back to normal?

Here is a picture.

[image]

Comment: It's probably caused by your system font/theme

Comment: tried changing that, doesn't do anything.

Comment: Just adding in a "me too." Ubuntu 14.04, applied updates and restarted this morning. I've been using this install for over a year, but today this happened.

Edit: Found more people who have this problem today, with various work-arounds : 
[AskUbuntu Thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/634502/chrome-tab-menu-url-bar-and-web-pages-have-got-really-big#new-answer), [Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/399cle/chrome_suddenly_low_resolution_large_tabs_and/)

Comment: A similar question is http://askubuntu.com/questions/634999/ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this chrome bug:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=498426

Apparently, running `google-chrome` with `--force-device-scale-factor` may fix it.

Comment: It doesn't for me. This seems to be a new bug that does the same as the old thing, but the old fix doesn't work.

Comment: Marking correct because it's a bug that's being fixed as I write this.

Comment: I've had to open my process manager and kill all chrome instances for this to work.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I don't have 50 rep on superuser so can't comment on the answer that *nearly* works.
`/opt/google/chrome/chrome --force-device-scale-factor=1`

did work for me. the answer above didn't have the `=1` so it may be the reason it didn't work for you.

Comment: interesting. It worked for me without the `=1`, as it happens.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative is to use [Chromium](https://www.chromium.org/Home).

You can install it using `sudo apt-get install chromium-browser`.

It features the same sign-in functionality and add-ons like Chrome does.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Sorry @DavidPostill, my intention was to comment because it's not a solution, but I didn't have enough reputation.